# How can I find unique users who downloaded app via an SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk

I implemented an SDK that tracks # of total installs of my iOS app, as well as paid installs.

I'd like to evaluate how many of these paid installs actually became users of my app. Is there a way for my app (or the SDK) to highlight a user who downloaded my app via this SDK?

I'm thinking of cross-referencing UDID or IFDA but cannot find anything here...

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: we are using [link] (http://welcome.freemyapps.com/advertise.html). What we'd like to do is the following. Say we have 1,000 new users/day, and 250 of them come via a third-party link (then tracked by an SDK). In this SDK dashboard (such as intercom), we don't know which user is which, and cannot match a unique user to his/her app events. Therefore, we know how many installs occur, but not what these people do. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, please see updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of third party SDKs that you can use to track user adoption.  [Parse](https://www.parse.com) and [Intercom](https://www.intercom.io) are two popular SDKs.  They can do what you ask for and more and the integration is fairly easy.

**Edited to Add:**

Based on your comment above I would use Parse.  You can log user actions that you choose (Objects) and you can log information that is tied to individual devices (Installation Object).  [Here are the docs on Objects](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects).  An example is shown below.

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
gameScore[@"score"] = @1337;
gameScore[@"playerName"] = @"Sean Plott";
gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @NO;
[gameScore saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
     if (succeeded) {
          // The object has been saved.
     } else {
         // There was a problem, check error.description
     }
}];
```

In the above code you create an object (on the fly which is a nice feature) and add a bunch of properties to it.  It is easy to put this in all parts of your code where you want to track how your users are interacting with your app.